# Cast non standard date/timestamp format varchar to date in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, date, datetime, parsing, presto

I have this non standard formatted date VARCHAR 'Wed Sep 29 16:10:03 UTC 2021' any idea on how to parse this to a date or timestamp?

I need a date in format dd/mm/yyyy

Have tried several iterations of `date_parse(last_login_date,'%R')` as date but always receive invalid format: "Fri Aug 14 19:17:14 UTC 2015" error.

Answer (score 0):

If all timestamps are UTC you can use next format:

```sql
select date_parse('Wed Sep 29 16:10:03 UTC 2021', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s UTC %Y');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-09-29 16:10:03.000 |

And then `date_format` with required one.

Some format specifiers potentially will needed to be changed (I used the ones with two digits for day and 24-hour 2 digits for hour), see the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions).

Otherwise you may need to switch to [java date parsing function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions).